# How to use string.translate() to translate this?

Tags: python, string, translate

first, I have this:

```
strSrc = '3.14'
```

And I hope the result is this:

```
strRst = '叁点壹肆'
```

P.s: The number '3' in traditional-Chinese is '叁'. Here:

> 0零    1壹  2贰  3叁  4肆  5伍  6陆  7柒  8捌  9玖

I want to translate `strSrc` into Chinese using **string.translate()**.

I check the [string.translate() doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate),it said:

> and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string

so, does that mean I should **NOT** use **string.translate()** to solve this problem??

---

but it always occurs encode problem, like this:

```
>>> engToChn = string.maketrans('0123456789.', '零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖点')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ValueError: maketrans arguments must have same length
```

---

if you try this:

```
>>> engToChn = string.maketrans('0123456789.', u'零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖点')
or
>>> engToChn = string.maketrans(u'0123456789.', u'零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖点')
```

it will this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in module
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Because `len('零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖点') == 33`. By making it a unicode object, `len(u'零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖点') == 11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Hanzi (chinese characters) don't fit into strings.

Try the following:

```
transtable = { ord("0"):u'零', ord("1"):u'壹', ....}
unicodestr = u"314"
print unicodestr.translate(transtable)
```

Comment: I think you are right, <Python cookbook> said like yours. I tried this, but, 'TypeError: expected a character buffer object.' WHY??

Comment: Whoops - a typo on my part - my unicode string is not, in fact, unicode string at all - I have will edit my example to change ` = "314"` to ` = u"314"`.

Comment: WOW, it works. Thank you:) This problem takes my all morning --! Really thanks:)

Comment: mei wenti :) glad I could get some reputation, I mean help.